# Sudakov's lower bound type inequality for supremum of Chi-squared random variables

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, measure-concentration, packing-and-covering

Let $\varepsilon$ be $n$-dimensional standard Gaussian veector, i.e., $\varepsilon \sim N_n(0, I_n)$. Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a subset of symmetric projection matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with $|\mathcal{P}| = K$. Also, assume that $\operatorname{rank}(P) =s$ for all $P \in \mathcal{P}$. Next, for a projection matrix $P \in \mathcal{P}$, define the random variable $Z_P = \varepsilon^\top P \varepsilon$, which follows $\chi^2_s$ distribution. My question is can we find a lower bound for
$$
\mathbb{E} \left(\max_{P \in \mathcal{P}} Z_P\right),
$$
in terms of a some sort of packing entropy of the set $\mathcal{P}$. My conjecture is the following:
$$
\mathbb{E} \left(\max_{P \in \mathcal{P}} Z_P\right) \geq s+ C\sup_{\delta>0} \delta^2 \log M(\delta, \mathcal{P}, \Vert \cdot\Vert), \quad (\text{$C$ is positive universal constant})
$$
where $ M(\delta, \mathcal{P}, \Vert \cdot\Vert)$ is an appropriate packing, or it could be some other quantity that captures the notion of minimum separability of the space $\mathcal{P}$. My initial try was to somehow use Sudakov's lower bound. For that, I did the following:
\begin{align}\tag{*}
\mathbb{E} \left(\max_{P \in \mathcal{P}} Z_P\right) &= \mathbb{E} \left(\max_{P \in \mathcal{P}} \Vert P \varepsilon\Vert_2^2 \right)\\
& = \mathbb{E} \left(\max_{P \in \mathcal{P}} \sup_{v: \Vert v\Vert_2 =1} v^\top P \varepsilon \right)^2\\
& \geq \left( \mathbb{E \; }\max_{P \in \mathcal{P}} \sup_{v: \Vert v\Vert_2 =1} v^\top P \varepsilon \right)^2 \quad (\text{Jensen's inequality})\\
& = \left( \mathbb{E }\; \sup_{v: \Vert v\Vert_2 =1} \max_{P \in \mathcal{P}}   v^\top P \varepsilon \right)^2 \quad (\text{supremum and max are interchangeable})\\
& \geq \left( \sup_{v: \Vert v\Vert_2 =1} \mathbb{E }\;    \max_{P \in \mathcal{P}} v^\top P \varepsilon \right)^2 
\end{align}
Now, using Sudakov's lower bound we cant get

$$
\mathbb{E }\;    \max_{P \in \mathcal{P}} v^\top P \varepsilon \geq C_1 r_v \sqrt{\log K},
$$
where $r_v : = \min \{ \Vert (P_1 - P_2)v\Vert_2 : P_1, P_2 \in \mathcal{P}, P_1 \neq P_2\}$. Here, we use the fact that the set $\{Pv : P \in \mathcal{P}\}$ is a $r_v$-packing of itself. Now, define $r_\max = \sup_{v : \Vert v\Vert_2 = 1} r_v$. Then, from $(*)$ it follows that

$$
\mathbb{E} \left(\max_{P \in \mathcal{P}} Z_P\right) \geq C r_\max^2 \log K.
$$
But this is definitely a loose bound as it is potentially missing the additive term $s$, which in my opinion should be there in the inequality. Is there any known result or reference related to such results? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are these supposed to be _orthogonal_ projections, i.e. the projection matrices are not only idempotent but also symmetric?

Comment: Yes, the projection matrices are symmetric. @MichaelHardy

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to mention in your posting that these are supposed to be _orthogonal_ projections, i.e. the matrices are symmetric. Not all projections are orthogonal projections; not all idempotent matrices are symmetric.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I have updated the post.